# SAS Using proc ttest or proc glm to factor a demographic variable into a comparison of two groups on an outcome measure

Tags: sas, glm

I have written SAS code to compare two groups for an outcome measure (i.e. reaction time - rt). However, we would like to factor in a demographic measure (i.e. IQ) to test whether the group differences in rt are actually driven by IQ differences between groups. I would like help in modifying my code. My existing code to compute basic group differences in rt is below. I have included code using both the t-test sas function and the glm sas function, which come out with similar results.

```
data sepdata  ;
infile "input.txt"  ;
     input subjid group IQ rt;
run;

title 'T-test group differences;
proc ttest;
        class group;
        var  rt;
run;

title 'Parallel glm code for group differences ';
proc glm;
 class group ;
 model  rt  = group ;
run;
```

I'd like help on modifying either the t-test function or the glm function to include "IQ" in the model.

Comment: How is IQ coded?  Is it discrete or continuous?

Answer (score 0):

To account for the effect of IQ on the response, include it as a predictor in your MODEL statement behind GROUP. The results associated with GROUP that come out of this updated model are then adjusted for IQ.

```
proc glm data = sepdata;
    class group;
    model rt = group iq;
run;
quit;
```

I think it would be reasonable in this case to consider IQ as continuous. I hope that helps!